# How to return a file using Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using *ASP.NET Web API*. 
 I want to download a PDF with C# from the API (that the API generates).

Can I just have the API return a `byte[]`? and for the C# application can I just do:

```
byte[] pdf = client.DownloadData("urlToAPI");?
```

and

```
File.WriteAllBytes()?
```

Comment: "the Web API"? What exactly do you mean? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The Web API is a new feature in the latest version of ASP.NET.  See http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc317096197

Comment: @Robert: Thanks - the tag makes it clearer, although referring to "the ASP.NET Web API" would have been clearer still. Partly MS's fault for a rubbishly generic name too :)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2012/02/23/more-about-rest-file-upload-download-service-with-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-phone-background-file-transfer.aspx

Comment: Anyone who lands wanting to return the stream via web api and IHTTPActionResult then see here: http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/02/downloading-an-inmemory-file-using-web-api-2/

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Better to return HttpResponseMessage with StreamContent inside of it.

Here is example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string id)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    string fileName;
    string localFilePath;
    int fileSize;

    localFilePath = getFileFromID(id, out fileName, out fileSize);
       
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

    return response;
}
```

**UPDATE** from comment by [patridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48700/patridge):
Should anyone else get here looking to send out a response from a byte array instead of an actual file, you're going to want to use `new ByteArrayContent(someData)` instead of `StreamContent` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467546/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-return-an-image-using-asp-net-web-api/12468615#12468615)).

Comment: First thing - this code will cause an exception since you're newing up two FileStream objects pointed at the same file. Second thing is that you do not want to use a "Using" statement, because as soon as the variable goes out of scope, .NET will dispose it and you'll get error messages about the underlying connection being closed.

Comment: Should anyone else get here looking to send out a response from a byte array instead of an actual file, you're going to want to use `new ByteArrayContent(someData)` instead of `StreamContent` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468615/48700)).

Comment: You may also want to override the base dispose() so you can handle your resources correctly when the framework calls it.

Comment: @patridge: Is `ByteArrayContent` better than `response.BinaryWrite`?

Comment: @IsaacKleinman I'm not sure. I haven't used `Response.BinaryWrite`. I'm guessing it would be throwing bytes at the stream directly rather than managing content using the Web API pipeline you have in place. If you have other processing steps in that API pipeline that need to run on the content before it heads down the wire, you may want to stick with `ByteArrayContent`. Best I can offer is to suggest you see what works best for your situation.

Comment: What is the `fileSize` variable used for in the above code? Should/could this be sent in the response headers?

Comment: This was a very helpful answer, but a user reported not being able to open pdf files returned to the client in this manner using Firefox. The files would open in Firefox as "filename.pdf.htm", which would cause the file not to open properly. Chrome, IE, Edge all worked fine. I found the solution was that you should also set the ContentType like this: response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

Comment: @mathias999us Updated code accordingly to your comment

Comment: I would like to point out that the correct MediaTypeHeaderValue is crucial and to get it dynamic if you have different file types you can do like this.
 (where fileName is a string and has a file type ending like .jpg, .pdf, docx etc..)
 
 var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
 response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

Comment: Does the FileStream get disposed automatically?

Answer (score 45):

Just a note for `.Net Core`: We can use the `FileContentResult` and set the contentType to `application/octet-stream` if we want to send the raw bytes. Example:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetDocumentBytes(int id)
{
    byte[] byteArray = GetDocumentByteArray(id);
    return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Comment: This works great, Also if you wanna control the file name there is a property on `FileContentResult` called `FileDownloadName` to specify the filename

Comment: @weeksdev ah didn't know that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thats it, thanks. Also comment from  weeksdev is very useful.

Comment: Thanks. This actually works for .NET Framework 4.8 as well.

Answer (score 44):

I made the follow action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/DownloadPdfFile/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadPdfFile(long id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    try
    {
        SQL.File file = db.Files.Where(b => b.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();

        if (file == null)
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
        else
        {
            // sendo file to client
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file.pdfBase64);


            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.name + ".pdf";
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually answers the question

Comment: This would not be a good idea with large files since it loads the entire image into memory.  The stream option is better.

Comment: @PaulReedy Perfect... but in a lot of cases, you don't need to deal with large files. But I totally agree with your point!

Answer (score 22):

Example with `IHttpActionResult` in `ApiController`.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("file/{id}/")]
public IHttpActionResult GetFileForCustomer(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
      return BadRequest();

    var file = GetFile(id);

    IHttpActionResult response;
    HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    responseMsg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file.SomeData);
    responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.FileName;
    responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    response = ResponseMessage(responseMsg);
    return response;
}
```

If you don't want to download the PDF and use a browsers built in PDF viewer instead remove the following two lines:

```
responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.FileName;
```

Comment: @ElbertJohnFelipe Yes, you get the file with `var file = GetFile(id);`. `file.SomeData` is a Byte Array (`byte[]`) and `file.FileName`is `string`.

Comment: Thank you for your post. 'HttpResponseMessage' didn't work for me inside an ApiController, so you saved me.

Answer (score 3):

You Can try , HttpClient for Download file from another side and same time you can pass as File Result

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/getFile")]
    public async  Task<FileResult> GetFile(string Param1,string Param2)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream stream = null;
            string strURL = @"File URL";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(strURL);
            Stream streamToReadFrom = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return File(streamToReadFrom, "{MIME TYPE}");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        { 
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been wondering if there was a simple way to download a file in a more ... "generic" way. I came up with this.

It's a simple `ActionResult` that will allow you to download a file from a controller call that returns an `IHttpActionResult`.
The file is stored in the `byte[] Content`. You can turn it into a stream if needs be.

I used this to return files stored in a database's varbinary column.

```
    public class FileHttpActionResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string MediaType { get; set; }
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

        public byte[] Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(StatusCode);

            response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
            response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Content));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaType);

            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A brief explanation of how your code fixes the OP's problem(s) would enhance the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to download file is to write the stream content to the response's body directly:

```
[HttpGet("pdfstream/{id}")]
public async Task  GetFile(long id)
{        
    var stream = GetStream(id);
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    Response.Headers.Add( HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, $"attachment; filename=\"{Guid.NewGuid()}.pdf\"" );
    Response.Headers.Add( HeaderNames.ContentType, "application/pdf"  );            
    await stream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body);
    await Response.Body.FlushAsync();           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt works as:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFileFromPath2(string guid)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();            
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var path = "C:\test";
            if (_fileHelper.ExtistFileFromPath(path, guid))
            {
                        memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, guid)));

                        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                        response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
                        
                        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = guid };
                        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                        response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
            }
            else
            {
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
                response.Content = new StringContent("File not found");
            }

            return response;
        }
```