# WCF Reference in HTML page

Tags: c#, html, wcf

My scenario is , i need a dynamic rendering of images on html page.

So basically if i have a following image on my html page

```
<img src="http://cms.com/Content/IMG0025.png" height="64" align="middle" width="62" />
```

i want to replace src with some service reference path (e.g. http://174.1.1.1/clientservice.svc/getimage()) so when this page is displayed . it calls a web service and dynamically return a image on the basis of mobile type (android or ios).

Comment: Even if its possible to do with WCF(not sure), it would be much easier if you create Web API, for this purpose. For reference you can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467546/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-return-an-image-using-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Yes you can use WCF for this, and in fact I think it would be *way* easier than webapi to set up. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/fetching-image-using-wcf-rest-service/