# System.Net.Http.HttpMethod cannot be serialized, WCF Web API

Tags: wcf-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am using the [HttpClient](http://nuget.org/packages/HttpClient) library to create a WCF Web API.

Snippet from service contract:

```
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {      
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Foo/{id}/{securityKey}/{filename}")]
        HttpResponseMessage Foo(int id, string securityKey);
    }
```

When I hit the .svc in a browser I am getting this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to
>   a WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>   contract: http://tempuri.org/:IMyService ---->
>   **System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpMethod' cannot be serialized**. Consider marking it
>   with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. 
>   If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

Does this make sense to anyone? The same code worked in a different project, all the libraries are the same in this case, there must be some nuance I am missing.

Comment: Why would you try and do that? HttpResponseMessage is intended to be an abstraction of an HTTP response. Not something to be serialized over the wire.

Comment: Are you trying to use WCF REST instead of Web API because you prefer the routing?   Try looking at the AttributeRouting extension for WebAPI.

Comment: You are not by chance using the old WCF REST Starter kit are you? http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20REST It was the predecessor to what now is Web API and is no longer supported. Are you trying to create a REST based WCF service using the `webHttpBinding` binding or ASP.NET Web API project?

Comment: @DarrelMiller  `HttpResponseMessage` is being used as the api is serving up images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125535/microsoft-web-api-return-a-file-use-byte. WCF api being used as this is a legacy service that pre-dated Web Api

Comment: Me too facing the same issue....any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Change your WCF operation signature to return a Stream. Then make sure you set the Content-type header. That will allow you to return images from a WCF Rest endpoint.