# Turning HttpWebResponse into an HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have the following action in an asp.net WebAPI controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCBERSS(string Site, string File, string User, string Password)
{
    string URLString = string.Format("https://{0}.rss.mycompany.com/{1}", Site, File);
    Uri uri = new Uri(URLString);
    CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
    cache.Add(uri, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(User, Password));
    WebRequest r = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    r.Credentials = cache;
    r.ContentType = "application/rss+xml";
    IgnoreBadCertificates();
    HttpWebResponse result = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
    return ???;
}
```

How can I convert the HttpWebResponse into an HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: See this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11125737/507793

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to transform HttpWebResponse  in HttpResponseMessage is create a new  HttpResponseMessage :

```cs
using (var responseApi = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
     var response = new HttpResponseMessage(responseApi.StatusCode);                    
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseApi.GetResponseStream()))
     {
         var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
         response.Content = new StringContent(objText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     }
     return response;
}
```

Comment: What about headers that were part of responseApi? Is there any need to keep any of those? Is there a generic way to handle this for all content types instead of hardcoding it to application/json?

Comment: This is in case of a successful request (HttpStatusCode.OK). How can I parse statusCode and reasonPhrase out of a ´HttpWebResponse´ if request is unsuccessful?