# Preferred method downloading byte array to client

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, arrays

I am curious about best practices.

I have a Windows Server hosting IIS ASP.NET Web App.

I have an image on the server.

I am downloading the image as a byte array from JavaScript by calling a generic handler which returns the byte array.

i.e.

```
var jpegByteArray = 'http://myurl/mygenericpage.ashx'
```

But I could do the same thing using a Web API and returning the JSON object.

What is the fastest, best way option to use?

Thanks

Comment: I think this has already been answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125535/microsoft-web-api-return-a-file-use-byte

Comment: hi, thanks for posting. +1 for the extra info but it does not tell me if it is better to use WebApi as opposed to using a generic handler? unless I am reading it wrong?