# Error 403 - I got 403 when return FileContentResult - Aspnet

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got an aspnet core API working well.

My frontend application has no problem with consuming simple datas from API.

But I've got a 403 error when I call an endpoint that returns a 'txt' file.
It occurs just only return a FileContentResult.
The 403 error generates an exception in my frontend, and the result that I expect comes inside error.response.data property. What a crazy thing!

The same endpoint returns 200 if I change the return from **FileContentResult** to **Ok()**, but obviously is not what I want.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: How are we supposed to help with your code if you dont post your code?

Comment: Did u look into this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125535/how-to-return-a-file-using-web-api

Comment: thx for replies.
@IndunilWithana I've tried that approach but it doesn't work.
I'm not using file path, but I'm creating a stream of data and transforming to bytes. So I'm returning 
`File(bytes,'application/octet-stream','myFileName.txt')`
If I find the solution I post here.