# How to Export an Excel File using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ajax, api, download

Helo, i already search on Google and here (StackOverflow) but no any solution i complete.

I Have a Excel file in my folder and i need to create a method on my controller to download this file.

And in my React Web Site i need to get this file to user computer.

I try to use ActionResult, FileStreamResult, HttpResponseMessage and other, read file from folder with File.ReadAllbytes, put the Header on response.

On the final i get this.

```
{ FileContents: "allcontentoffilehere....", Contenttype: "application/octet-stream", FileDownloadName: "filename.xls"}
```

And using this JavaScript do download:

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(responseDownloadFile.data.FileContents);
                var blob = new Blob([bytes], {
                    type: responseDownloadFile.data.ContentType
                });

                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = responseDownloadFile.data.FileDownloadName;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
```

But the file when download is corrupted.

Any on can help me?

Comment: Solution from Microsoft did not work?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects

Comment: I assume you have generated the file and want to download it from an ASP.NET Web Api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125535/how-to-return-a-file-using-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Try to  return HttpResponseMessage type on your API

```
                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent([file bytes]);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/file type");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "filename.xlsx"
            };

            return result;
```

And on your Front end execute code:

```
window.location.href = "link to your api endpoint to download excel";
```