# How to handle filename at response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));

Tags: c#, api

Getting Null exception

```
try
{
var contentBytes = APIWebservice.GetPreview(Global.AuthTicket?.Ticket, fileToken, out var fileName,
out var isAuthenticated);

if (!isAuthenticated)
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Not authorized");

var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new ByteArrayContent(contentBytes)};
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Size = contentBytes.Length;

return response;
}
```

Getting issue at response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));

**"System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders.ContentDisposition.get returned null."**

But the out var fileName having value.

Please..

Comment: What is the filename?  The filename was added in the server code and you may not have access to the folder where the file is stored.

Comment: Even I hardcode the filename, still getting the same issue.
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "TestName.png";

Comment: Is the file on the machine? Do you have read access?

Comment: Yes we have a read access, if I comment that particular line, I can see the file.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125535/how-to-return-a-file-using-web-api